# h2 before the h1. HTML5 outlines

Tags: html

I have a title for a page and I give it a h1. Then I have a small text that explains the context of the subject in the title. Here I use h2. But in this case I prefer to put that h2 before the h1. I think this is better from a design and a concept point of view.

```
<h2 id="topTitle"> Top title. Explains the context of the title </h2>
<h1 id="title"> Title of the page </h1>

<p> Some text in a paragraf </p>
```

If I use the outlines tools (Chrome or the Outliner) this tools give this:
1. Top title (h2)
2. Title of the page (h1)

But the real structure of the page should be:
1. Title  (h1)
      1.1. Top title (h2)

I know that I can reflect the real structure of the page if I put the h2 after the h1. But to put the top title before the title, helps to explain different things to the user of the web. An introductory heading is useful.

How should I reflect well the top titles or introductory titles in the outline?

Comment: `<hx>` tags are used to outline your document.  They can be (re-)styled using CSS, if you want.  Why do you want to put the `<h2>` first?  Why not do `<h1>Top title<h1> <h2> Title of page</h2>`?

Comment: since design decision questions are somewhat subjective, they are better suited for a site like [programmers.se]. [so] is for questions that have objective answers.

Comment: I do not think this is a design question. Top titles are needed because they have a different meaning that subtitles. So, the question is: how to use top titles and make them reflect the right structure of the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could simply do without marking topTitle as headline and just apply some styling (like big bold font) to make it look "right". the tools to extract structure would skip it, but i think this is the right thing to do when it is an introduction explaining the title.

Comment: This is a good option. Another possibility is tho wrap h1 and h2 in a hgroup. This way only the h1 will be in the outline. Anyway the outline would reflect better the content if  the h2 appear in the outline and is after the h1

Comment: hgroup will be deleted, Don't use it.

Comment: @FC. that is true, I did not notice. Thank you!

Comment: Can you show us an exemple of your full titles ?
Maybe you could merge them into only one h1 (or h2)

Comment: Ok. h2 could not be the best option to show such information.
If it's always the same structure, like "Posts for DATE", i think that you should put this in a span tag, or similar.
If the content change a lot and is unique or few repeated, put it in h2.

Answer (score 0):

No problem with your structure (for SEO).
Just try to not skip a level, like a h4 after a h2 if there is no h3 on your page.

The problem is not the design, you are not really supposed to keep your tags with their defaults styles.

Comment: The problem is that if I put the h2 before the h1, in the structure of the page the h2 is more important than the h1 and this does not reflect the reality.

Comment: The h1 will always be more "important", the position is not a problem. Don't worry, just do what is best for your design, be coherent and it will be fine. If you're really affraid to do that, you can still put the h1 before the h2 and modify it's position with css. But I don't think this is the right thing to do.

Comment: 'The h1 will always be more "important"' - unless search engines give up on headings as a content signal.

Comment: Sure, you're right, and this is - (personnal advice) - what is slowly happening. That's why I think he should'nt be worried too much about this.